# How to use FParsec to parse into a record or object?

Tags: sdp, fparsec

After completing the FParsec tutorial, I decided to try writing a parser for SDP 
(Session Description Protocol RFC 4366) - at least the first 3 lines. SDP is specified in ABNF (RFC 4234)); so, I’m trying to work from that.

The note at the end of User's Guide Section 5.1 pointed the way “You start with simple parsers for the leaf nodes of your grammar and then work your way up step‐by‐step until you eventually obtain a parser for the complete grammar.” With that direction and the tipss from Stephan's answer to use pipes, here's what I have now:

```
open FParsec
open System.Net

// handy for debugging, supposedly, but I couldn't get it to work
let breakParse (p: Parser<_,_>) stream =
  p stream

// Input
let session = "v=0
o=jdoe 2890844526 2890842807 IN IP4 10.47.16.5
s=SDP Seminar
"

type Sdp = 
  { Version : System.UInt16;
    Origin : Owner;
    SessionName : string }

and Owner = 
  { Username : string
    SessionId : string
    SessionVersion : string
    NetType : NetworkType
    AddrType : AddressType
    Address : UnicastAddress }

and NetworkType = 
  | Undefined
  | Internet

and AddressType = 
  | Undefined
  | IPv4
  | IPv6

and UnicastAddress =
  | IPaddress of System.Net.IPAddress
  | FQDomainName of string
  | ExternalAddress of string

let sep : Parser<unit, unit> = skipChar '='
let getValue typeChar = skipChar typeChar .>> sep
let many1Digit : Parser<string, unit> = many1Satisfy isDigit
let many1Hex : Parser<string, unit> = many1Satisfy isHex

let nonWhitespace : Parser<string, unit> = many1Satisfy (isNoneOf @" \n\r\t") 

//proto-version = %x76 "=" 1*DIGIT CRLF
let getVersion = getValue 'v' >>. many1Digit .>> spaces |>> System.Convert.ToUInt16

//origin-field = %x6f "=" username SP sess-id SP sess-version SP
//               nettype SP addrtype SP unicast-address CRLF
// username cannot contain whitespace; i.e., only visible chars
let getUsername : Parser<string, unit> = getValue 'o' >>. nonWhitespace .>> spaces

//sess-id = 1*DIGIT
let getSessionId = many1Digit .>> spaces

//sess-version = 1*DIGIT
let getSessionVersion = many1Digit .>> spaces

let getNetType : Parser<NetworkType, unit> = 
  pstring "IN" |>> (function 
  | "IN" -> NetworkType.Internet
  | _ -> NetworkType.Undefined)
  .>> spaces

let getAddrType : Parser<AddressType, unit> = 
  anyString 3 |>> (function 
  | "IP4" -> AddressType.IPv4
  | "IP6" -> AddressType.IPv6
  | _ -> AddressType.Undefined)
  .>> spaces

let getAddress : Parser<UnicastAddress, unit> = 
    (restOfLine true) |>> (fun a -> IPAddress.Parse a |> IPaddress )

let getUserSession = pipe3 getUsername getSessionId getSessionVersion (fun u i v -> (u, i, v))
let pipeOrigin = pipe4 getUserSession getNetType getAddrType getAddress 
              (fun us n t a -> 
                let u, i, v = us
                {Username=u; SessionId=i; SessionVersion=v; NetType=n; 
                  AddrType=t; Address=a})

//session-name-field =  %x73 "=" text CRLF
let getSessionName = getValue 's' >>. restOfLine true

let threelines = pipe3 getVersion pipeOrigin getSessionName 
              (fun v o sn -> {Version=v; Origin=o; SessionName=sn})

let sessionDesc = run threelines session
```

And this works (except that getAddress doesn't handle FQDN or external addresses yet), with this result:

```
val sessionDesc : ParserResult<Sdp,unit> =
  Success: {Version = 0us;
 Origin = {Username = "jdoe";
           SessionId = "2890844526";
           SessionVersion = "2890842807";
           NetType = Internet;
           AddrType = IPv4;
           Address = IPaddress 10.47.16.5;};
 SessionName = "SDP Seminar";}
```

And now this is the target Record type Sdp. But it is a bit of a convoluted way of getting the results into the output by going through some tuples.

I’ve read into the User’s Guide through to Section 5.4, but all the examples parse into discriminated unions.  Is a Record type the best choice for collating results; or, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`pipe` functions](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#sequentially-applying-parsers) to sequentially apply the parsers for the lines and then construct a record. (If you need more than 5 temporaries you can easily combine multiple `pipex` combinators to create a `pipe` combinators with more arguments.)

Your parsers for the first three lines don't seem complete yet.

Comment: Per your recommendation, I edited the question with updated code using pipe combinators; but, I'm not yet satisfied with going to tuples, then to a record.  Maybe you had something more direct in mind for constructing the record?

Comment: Using a `pipe` combinator you could create a record like e.g. in `pipe3 getVersion pipeOrigin getSessionName (fun v o sn -> {Version = v; Origin = o; SessionName = sn})`, though in your case you'd still have to make `getVersion` return a `uint16` and `pipeOrigin` an `Owner`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I've updated the code with your recommended changes and that yields the desired record.  I'm still wondering, though, if maybe an object with automatic properties would be preferable to a record...esp., as I continue parsing the additional lines of a session description?

Comment: @StephanTolksdorf any chance of releasing an official PCL version of the FParsec? There is a fork - please see comments:

https://bitbucket.org/fparsec/main/issue/29/portable-version-of-fparsec

Comment: I've added a comment to the bitbucket issue. However, I don't think using StackOverflow comments in this way is appropriate. I'd prefer if you could just email me directly at fparsec @ quanttec.com.